# Generate INSERT script with Sequence Next Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am currently working on a data migration where exporting data from on-prem server and importing on the Azure SQL.

I using "Generate Script" with **Data Only** and database has sequences for the master table but when the INSERT scripts generates it simply includes columns values.

In order to align with the sequences, I am looking for a solution to generate a INSERT script using the NEXT VALUE to accommodate the sequences itself in the INSERT statement.

The other approach I am thinking to import the data and RESET the sequences with new START value.

Any other solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you import the data with the already assigned sequence value and then reset the sequence in the target database after the import:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE YourSequence
    RESTART WITH <specify max value here>;
```

Comment: That's what I am planning to do.. Thank you!